# Using a sequence in CreateML to record device motion

Tags: machine-learning, coreml, devicemotion, createml

so I want to train a MLClassifier to identify a specific device motion.
So what I did was to record the motion data and very recorded data I labeled accordingly. When that didn't quite worked as I hoped, I started to realize that I have to record the "motion" itself and not only momentarily.

So I packed 5 dataSets (dictionaries) in a row and that was my new training feature. So I thought, but trying to train my new data I watched this error trying to create my Classifier:

> Value encountered in column 's' is of type 'dictionary' cannot be
>   mapped to a categorical value. Categorical values must be integer,
>   strings, or None.

Now I'm slowly giving up... Has anyone of you a suggestion or know why I can't use sequences (arrays) as features?

...

Btw, here is some sample data of my JSON:

`[{"s":[{"rZ":-1.0,"p":0.2,"aY":-0.0,"rX":1.5,"y":0.1,"r":-1.3,"aZ":0.2,"rY":-2.8,"aX":0.6},{"rZ":-1.9,"p":0.2,"aY":0.0,"rX":2.0,"y":0.2,"r":-1.4,"aZ":0.0,"rY":-3.2,"aX":0.5},{"rZ":-1.8,"p":0.3,"aY":0.0,"rX":2.4,"y":0.2,"r":-1.5,"aZ":0.9,"rY":-4.8,"aX":0.5},{"rZ":-1.6,"p":0.3,"aY":0.0,"rX":2.5,"y":0.3,"r":-1.6,"aZ":0.9,"rY":-3.8,"aX":0.6},{"rZ":-1.8,"p":0.3,"aY":0.1,"rX":2.2,"y":0.3,"r":-1.7,"aZ":0.1,"rY":-3.0,"aX":0.6}],"v":0}]`

And the code I use to create my model:

```
do{
    let a = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: dummyJSONurl)
    let recognizer = try MLClassifier(trainingData: a, targetColumn: "v")
}catch let er{
    er
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use sequences because `MLClassifier` isn't a classifier that can work on sequences. Perhaps Apple will add this in a future release but for now it appears that you'll have to use a more capable tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought so but didn't found anything about it, also there is a MLSequence and a MLDataValue.ValueType.sequence but nothing.. guess I'll have to train my model somewhere else .-.

btw, if you have any sources for your statement feel free to add a link sorry sth ^^

Comment: MLSequence is part of Core ML. MLClassifier and MLDataTable are part of Create ML. These are different frameworks. The reason I know MLClassifier doesn't work on sequences is that the five types of models it supports right now (decision tree, random forest, boosted tree, logistic regression, SVM) do not naturally work on sequences.